# Spring MVC project as jar

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new to Spring MVC and I have now come accross tutorials that explain how to deploy your web project as a .jar. My IDE is the Spring Tool Suite. I have always used .war + Apache Tomcat.

Can someone elaborate a bit from the practical point of view why to use .jar instead of .war? Any problems to be aware of?

edit: other answers are welcome too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot uses fat JAR packaging where is embeds Servlet container with all dependencies into this single JAR.

If you are using Maven, it uses `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to package the project.

Practical usage of this approach is simple. Ability to easily run Srvlet based Spring application from command line with externalized properties. Such configuration enables powerfully orchestration possibilities which are often used in modern enterprises in so called Microservices or SOA architecture.

There is group of people out there (including myself) which believe that deploying various WAR files of unrelated applications into single Servlet runtime is not very good idea.

So fat JARs are handy for separate Servlet runtime per application deployment.

Comment: Do I get 100% functionality with .jar as I would get with Tomcat + .war? Do I even need Tomcat, if I go with the .jar version?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat is as if you would deploy single war on standalone Tomcat. But if you need configure Tomcat, you need to do it via Spring Boot properties.

Comment: Can one host .jar and  Tomcat + .war files on the same machine? Any good site to read about all that specific stuff?

Comment: Sure you can. Don't know any specific resources.

Comment: "Do I even need Tomcat" strictly speaking no, the tomcat is part of your jar, you don't need to use tomcat, you could also choose to use seomthing else, for example jetty. But for the app to be self-contained and runnable, some kind of server needs to be 'included' in the jar. If you are really asking if you need a 'separate' tomcat installed to your machine the answer is 'no'. The jar needs just one thing to run: a JVM.

Answer (score 2):

About having .jar and Tomcat + .war on the same machine, it is possible and I use this. This may be not cool but I had a .war application running in a tomcat server before the rise up of spring boot. Now my new apps are spring boot apps, and we are migrating our architecture to SOA concept, but we can't change the tire with the moving car. The main application, the WAR is running in a tomcat server and the others (.jar) are self contained ( embedded tomcat ), each one running in a different port. It was the most viable solution available for us by the moment.

Comment: could you explain a bit how you assigned every .jar a different port?

Comment: The port issue is configured in your app. In my war app this configuration is located in my pom.xml. I use the tomcat7-maven-plugin where you configure the specifics, like the port. In the spring-boot app, this configuration about the port is made in a .properties file. The line is server.port= 8081. But as I told you, this is not the ideal architecture scheme. You can run all your app services in the same port in your server by using docker ( take a look ! ). I am using different ports to facilitate the development and deployment in production, but I intend to move to docker soon.